Unable to sell using OKX swap API but can sell using the web widget
Hi I am writing some code to sell off my tokens automatically using the OKX swap, I have a weird problem where I can sell using an OKX web widget on any given DEX website, but unable to complete the transaction on my code. Here is a snippet of how I execute the transfer on my end. Would appreciate some thoughts here , thank you!
def swap_tokens_okx(from_token, to_token, amount, slippage=None):
    # Get decimals for the from_token
    from_token_decimals = get_token_decimals(from_token)

    # Adjust the amount based on decimals
    adjusted_amount = int(amount * (10 ** from_token_decimals))

    # Get quote
    quote = get_quote(from_token, to_token, adjusted_amount)

    # adjust slippage
    if slippage is None:
        slippage = estimate_slippage(quote)  # Default slippage
    else:
        slippage = slippage / 100

    # Get swap data
    swap_data = get_swap_data(from_token, to_token, adjusted_amount, slippage)

    if 'data' not in swap_data or not swap_data['data']:
        return (None, 400)

    tx_data = swap_data['data'][0]['tx']
    
    # Prepare transaction
    base_fee = W3.eth.get_block('latest')['baseFeePerGas']
    max_priority_fee = int(tx_data['maxPriorityFeePerGas'])

    max_fee_per_gas = int(base_fee * 2 + max_priority_fee)  # Ensure max fee covers base fee and tip

    transaction = {
        'to': Web3.to_checksum_address(tx_data['to']),
        'value': int(tx_data['value']),
        'gas': int(int(tx_data['gas']) * 1.5),  # Add 50% to estimated gas
        'maxFeePerGas': max_fee_per_gas,
        'maxPriorityFeePerGas': int(max_priority_fee),
        'data': tx_data['data'],
        'chainId': CHAIN_ID,
        'from': ACCOUNT_ADDRESS,
    }

    # If from_token is not ETH, we need to approve the contract first
    if from_token.lower() != "0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee":
        allowance, nonce = check_and_approve_token(from_token, OKX_APPROVAL_ADDRESS, adjusted_amount)
        if not allowance:
            return (None, 400)
        
    if not nonce:
        transaction['nonce'] = get_transaction_count()
    else:
        transaction['nonce'] = nonce + 1

    # Sign and send transaction
    tx_hash, tx_receipt = sign_and_send_transaction(transaction)

    # Check if the transaction was successful
    if tx_receipt['status'] == 1:
        logger.info(f"Transaction successful: {tx_hash.hex()}")
        return (tx_hash.hex(), 200)
    else:
        logger.error(f"Transaction failed: {tx_hash.hex()}")
        return (tx_hash.hex(), 400)

I tried changing gas, but when comparing requests on basescan, the gas I paid on the failed transactions seemed to match, so I am not really sure where to go from here.
